# gitorious doesn't up as virtual host

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, ruby-on-rails, git

I am trying to set up a gitorious instance, but I keep getting mis-directed. I am using passenger to host the rails app. This is the part from the vhosts file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName git.domain.org
    DocumentRoot /usr/share/webapps/gitorious/public
    RailsEnv production
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/rails_error_log
</VirtualHost>
```

going to the domain in my browser usually tried to direct to localhost.localdomain, which yields a problem loading page.
The error log is blank.

Answer (score 2):

Found the problem. The gitorious.yml database had `localhost.localdomain` as the host name. Chaning it to my IP brings it up.